# Get value of static property without knowing the class name

Tags: java, static, extends

Suppose I have an abstract class `Game`:

```
public abstract class Game
{
    public static final int FRAME_LENGTH = 40;

    public static int getFrameLength() {
        return Game.FRAME_LENGTH; //What do I have to replace Game with?
    }
}
```

And there is the class `App` which extends `Game`:

```
public class App extends Game
{
    private static final int FRAME_LENGTH = 50;
}
```

Now, when the method `App.main()` is executed, it prints `40`, I would have expected `50`, as `App` has overwritten the value of `FRAME_LENGTH`. I guess I would have to use something like `self` in the `Game` class, except java has no `self`.

How am I supposed to access the static property `App.FRAME_LENGTH` without knowing beforehand that the child class will be called `App`?

### Edit

Okay, based on the first answer, I think I have to specify my question a little.

First, I change the scope of `FRAME_LENGTH` to `public`. For the sake of this question, this makes things easier. Second, I changed the method `getFrameLength` which was previously called `main`.

The problem I am facing: Right now, I do not know which classes will extend `Game`, and `Game` should not need to know, either.

If you look at the code, you will be able to see that `Game.FRAME_LENGTH` is `40` and `App.FRAME_LENGTH` is `50`. `Game.getFrameLength()` returns `40` as expected, but `App.getFrameLength()` returns `50`, I would expect (or rather want) it to return `50`.

My question now is very simple: In the above code, what do I have to change `return Game.FRAME_LENGTH;` to, so it returns the correct value (meaning the value of `FRAME_LENGTH` of the class the method is called on), similar to `self::$frameLength` in PHP.

Comment: Override getFrameLength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the `App.FRAME_LENGTH` varible from the main method, because it's defined as a `private` to the `App` class.

Also, you are **not** overriding the variable value (by extending the class). The class inheritance has nothing to do with `static` members

---

Update:

Seems like you don't need the `static` modifier at all. What you have to do is the following:

```
public abstract class Game {
    private final int FRAME_LENGTH = 40;

    public int getFrameLength() {
        return this.getValue();   //<-- Note the usage of the "this" keyword.
    }

    // Every subclass of Game must implement this method 
    // and return their specific FRAME_LENGTH value
    public abstract int getValue();  
}
```

By using the `this` keyword, we're actually invoking the *current* instace (which can be a subclass) of the `Game` class.

Now, an example subclass of the `Game` can provide a different value of `FRAME_LENGTH`.

```
public class App extends Game {
    private final int FRAME_LENGTH = 50;

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return FRAME_LENGTH;
    }
}
```

Now, when invoking `new App().getFrameLength()` you will actually return the result of `App#getValue()` implementation and thus will receive `50`. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] agrs) {
    System.out.println(new App().getFrameLength());
}
```

Comment: Wait a minute. If `FRAME_LENGTH` was public, I could (from anywhere) access `App.FRAME_LENGTH` and get `50`, right? Now, when I run the method `App.main`, it needs to access that value. But if there were another class, say `Example` extending `Game`, when I run `Example.main`, the value in `Example.FRAME_LENGTH` should be used. How do I define that in `Game.main`?

Comment: When you type `SomeClass.FRAME_LENGTH` the compiler will try to access the static member of `SomeClass` called `FRAME_LENGTH`. Depending on the type of the accessor (`public`, `private`, etc.) it will be accessible or not.
If you want to get the `App.FRAME_LENGTH` from `Game`, you have to change the `private` modifier of the `App`'s `FRAME_LENGTH` varible to more wider scope.

Comment: I overhauled my question a bit, I hope it is clearer now what exactly I am asking.

Comment: I actually need `static` in this case, but for some other reasons, which have nothing to do with the issue here. Is there really no way to access a static property of the current class without explicitly using the class name?

Comment: Well...no. `static` variables don't have relation to class instances. They are only bound to the class definition and are accessed via the `ClassName.StaticVariable` pattern.